# Switch Statement with getElementById expression

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, checkbox, switch-statement

Is it possible to make a "Switch" statement with expression of method "getElementByName" in order to check if the checkboxes have the same name?

This is my function:

```
function finalOutput() {
var text, text2, q = document.getElementByName("checker").value;

switch(q){
    case 1:
        text = "my role is role1";
    break;
    case 2:
        text = "my role is role2";
    break;
    case 3:
        text = "my role is role3";
    break;
    case 4:
        text2 = "my parameter is parameter1";
    break;
    case 5:
        text2 = "my parameter is parameter2";
    break;
    case 6:
        text2 = "my parameter is parameter3";
    break;
    default:
    text = "Please check if you fill all details...";
    }
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text;
document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = text2;
}
```

---

This is the checkboxes in html:

```
role1:  <input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" 
value="1" name="checker"/> </br>
role2:  <input type="checkbox" id="2" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)"         
value="2" name="checker"/> </br>
role3:  <input type="checkbox" id="3" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)"     
value="3" name="checker"/> </br>
parameter1:  <input type="checkbox" id="4" 
onclick="selectOnlyThis2(this.id)" value="4" name="checker" /> </br>
parameter2:  <input type="checkbox" id="5" 
onclick="selectOnlyThis2(this.id)" value="5" name="checker" /> </br>
parameter3:  <input type="checkbox" id="6" 
onclick="selectOnlyThis2(this.id)" value="6" name="checker" />
```

I want that the switch will get the value of each checkbox and it will do what im told him accordingly.
I think that the problem is with the cases of switch but not sure.
I tried to do it with "if" but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve] - where is selectOnlythis?

Comment: If you change function `finalOutput() {` to `selectOnlyThis(q)` and remove ` q = document.getElementByName("checker").value;` your code will likely work better

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

If you switch on q, you need to test "1" etc, if you want q===1 you need +q to convert to a number

```js
function selectOnlyThis(q) {
  var text = "Please check if you fill all details...",
     text2 = "";
     console.log(q)
  switch (+q) {
    case 1:
      text = "my role is role1";
      break;
    case 2:
      text = "my role is role2";
      break;
    case 3:
      text = "my role is role3";
      break;
    case 4:
      text2 = "my parameter is parameter1";
      break;
    case 5:
      text2 = "my parameter is parameter2";
      break;
    case 6:
      text2 = "my parameter is parameter3";
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = text2;
}
```

```html
role1:      <input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" value="1" name="checker" /> </br>
role2:      <input type="checkbox" id="2" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" value="2" name="checker" /> </br>
role3:      <input type="checkbox" id="3" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" value="3" name="checker" /> </br>
parameter1: <input type="checkbox" id="4" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" value="4" name="checker" /> </br>
parameter2: <input type="checkbox" id="5" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" value="5" name="checker" /> </br>
parameter3: <input type="checkbox" id="6" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" value="6" name="checker" />
<span  id="output"></span>
<span  id="output2"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to correct the function name **document.getElementsByName("q");** there is a 's' missing in your code.

Second of all, if you have 3 or N elements with the same **name** the object "document" is gonna to return for you a list with **3 or N** objects for exemple:

```
<div class="ps-relative">
    <input name="q" type="text" value="test" />
    <input name="q" type="text" value="Hello world" />
</div>

var myElements = document.getElementsByName("q");

myElements[0] // has the input element including his value 'test'
alert(myElements[0].value);

myElements[1] // has the input element including his value 'Hello world'
alert(myElements[1].value);
```

> Note. To pass through all elements you have to iterating with 'for looping', 'while looping' or recursively. In case of the amount of elements are fixed you can used the Index position. I do not recommend to do it, because it is not considered a good practice.